# How to do authentication using REST API in Java for Sharepoint 2016?

Tags: java, rest, cookies, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

We have a tenant server of Sharepoint. I need to upload a document on Sharepoint using Java?

I'm able to upload document using Advanced REST client after retriving `X-RequestDigest` value.

But problem is that here I'm manually putting FedAuth, rtFa cookie from browser after logging through browser.

Please help me how to get these cookies programmatically using HTTP `POST`.

[image: Rest client]

Comment: Which java library do you use for that? Show any code snippet.

Comment: @SergeyMorozov, currently Im not using any library. Im trying to connect it with REST Api client only.

Comment: @SergeyMorozov, which java library should I use? Better if we dont use any third party library.

Comment: Try to use java.net.HttpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("X-RequestDigest", <value_you_need>)

Comment: @SergeyMorozov to get X-RequestDige‌​st value, we need to get authentication cookies. From browser Im able to get FedAuth, rtFa cookies and usnig those Im able to get X-RequestDige‌​st value and later file upload. How to get authentication cookies by not using browser?

Comment: with out using browser you can not get the auth cookie. you need to open a brower pop up to login to the sharepoint site and after the successful login read the cookie and close the login popup.

Comment: @Konammagari, I will be using these REST Apis form Java program. How can we Authenticate then?

Comment: Trigger the SharePoint site and that will redirect the user to login page, after the user logs in to the site read the authentication cookie from the browser.with this cookie you can use rest APIs.

Comment: @Konammagari, as of now Im doing the same. But how will java program run ? How to do authentication when you are making a java client for uploading document on sharepoint?

Comment: I am not aware of java client, can you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the <s>X-RequestDigest</s> FormDigestValue, which then will be the value used for the X-RequestDigest in every other POST call, with a POST call from http://whatever.com/YourSite/_api/contextinfo

Edit:
The value you get is your authentication which you have to use for every other POST call.

Comment: Thanks. To make this POST call we need to authenticate first. How to that?

Comment: No, you don't need to authenticate to make a POST call to /_api/contextinfo

Comment: Then anyone can do the POST call and get the access to update Sharepoint. That is not the case. You need to put accesstoken I believe.

Comment: Yes, anyone can do the POST call to /_api/contextinfo. It doesn't give you the permissions to update/write automatically. Your user still needs update/write permissions on the requested site, which is configured in SharePoint. The X-RequestDigest contains the user information and a time based token.  You have to get the FormDigestValue (which is the value for the X-RequestDigest) from the POST call to /_api/contextinfo.